# How can I isolate unit tests by class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest

I have a number of 'unit tests' (they're really integration tests) in several classes that access a shared resource, and I want each test class to only acquire the resource once (for performance reasons).

However, I'm getting issues when I release the resource in `[ClassCleanup]`, because that isn't running until all tests are completed.

Here's a simplified example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

static class State
{
    public static string Thing;
}
[TestClass]
public class ClassA
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext ctx)
    {
        State.Thing = "Hello, World!";
    }
    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        State.Thing = null;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestA()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(State.Thing); // Verify we have a good state
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class ClassB
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestB()
    {
        Assert.IsNull(State.Thing); // Verify we have an uninitialized state
        // Initialize state, do stuff with it
    }
}
```

On my machine at least, `TestB` fails because it runs before `ClassA` has been cleaned up.

I read [ClassCleanup May Run Later Than You Think](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/01/06/classcleanupmayrunlaterthanyouthink.aspx), but that doesn't explain any way to change the behaviour. And I realize I shouldn't depend on test ordering, but it's too expensive to re-acquire the resource for every test, so I want to group them by class.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to force each test class to run as a unit, and make the cleanup occur immediately?

Comment: Make a call inside TestB then it will work indendently

Comment: @AmitAgrawal What do you mean, "make a call"?

Comment: Unit tests are such that they can be run in any order. I can suggest that make a local copy of the resource in each test class. That way at least the classes are somewhat independent.

Comment: @AD.Net Unfortunately the resource isn't the type can be copied. There's only on instance available (at least given the current implementation).

Comment: And it's initialization is different in ClassA and ClassB?

Comment: Why not make access static, with a static constructor that does your required setup, and a finalize method that does your cleanup?

Comment: @NamelessOne It's set up differently in different places. There are tests that test different configurations of it, including acquiring and releasing multiple times.

Comment: I hate to suggest this: Put a wrapper around the static state that counts test references.  Do tear down and set up in class initialize and then increment reference counts in test initialize and decrement them in test cleanup.  Use a spin lock in class initialize to confirm that reference count is zero.  This will only work if you can make sure each test class runs 1 after another.  I can't remember if that is true or configurable with MSTest. (I'm assuming you can't mock this static resource in any meaningful way.)

Answer (score 0):

Although `ClassCleanup` might be unreliable in terms of when it is run, `ClassInitialize` is not; why not give each testclass that relies on this shared resource a `ClassInitialize` that cleans up the shared resource of the previous test class (if any), right before acquiring the resource itself?

The only time the shared resource isn't released is for the last test class, but you could handle that with the `ClassCleanup` because then it doesn't matter anymore when it is run (since there won't be any more test classes following it).

Comment: I discovered that some of my tests are actually running between tests from the other class. I had to do some epic gymnastics to get a temporary solution for that. Do you have any ideas on how to get the tests to run grouped by class? The best thing I can think of is an ordered test, or possibly creating a new project.

Comment: @KendallFrey To be honest I hadn't thought of that it would mix tests from different test classes. If there really isn't a away to share that resource between test classes, then ordered tests are probably your best bet (I don't think there's such a thing as partially ordered tests)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you cannot make this resource shared by the entire assembly all at once? Make it an internal or public static variable in one of the test classes (or a separate designated class), and refer to it directly from all the test classes. The initialization of the resource will take place in the [AssemblyInitialize] method and the cleanup will take place at the [AssemblyCleanup].

Comment: Unfortunately the tests in different classes required different configuration etc. so it couldn't be shared. My ultimate workaround solution was to split the tests into separate assemblies that could share it, although it did generate a bit of a profusion of mostly meaningless test projects.